# Bevel Geometry and Array Modifier on a Polyline Curve Has Varying or Uneven Thickness

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, bevel, curve-modifier

I'm trying to make a curve that has some geometry applied to it. My two options are bevel geometry or array modifier. This is what I have so far.
Following one is the result of bevel geometry on a polyline curve, the shape is shown on the bottom left. Please note that it gets thinner on sharp corners.
[image]

Following is the result of array modifier, the object is show on the bottom left. This is even more uneven
[image]

Finally, the following is what I want. nice even thickness all the way round. I made this my varying the radii of the vertices on a beveled curve but that's only a stop gap solution my final product is going to be too complex to apply the same method.
[image]

Comment: If the object is to be flat, and mitred, make the curve 2D in its geometry panel.

Comment: @RobinBetts That did it. I did not expect it to be that simple. I'm glad that it is.

Comment: Great! This Q may get clobbered, (no offence), there are duplicates out there but I can't find them atm